# list index out of range

Tags: python, list, indexing

how is this possible, I have a list called "temp".  This is what I have in my python interpreter.

```
In [150]: len(temp)
Out[150]: 773942

In [151]: temp[773942]
```

and I get an IndexError: list index out of range.

I'm confused because it just told me that there are 773942 values in the list, and now it tells me that the index is out of range?

Comment: This almost sounds like you're kidding.  A list of 3 elements are numbered 0, 1 and 2.  What's your **real** question?

Answer (score 11):

The indices of a list are in the range from `0` to `len(temp) - 1`.  Your index is one past the end.

For example a list of length three has the following indices:

```
["a",   "b",   "c"]
 ^      ^      ^
 0      1      2
```

Accessing index `3` would be one past the end.

Answer (score 1):

indexes are zero-based so last element is len() - 1

Answer (score 0):

In python `len()` returns how many elements there are in your list. However indexes start at 0. So for example:

```
>>>a = [1,2,3]
>>>len(a)
3
>>>a[0]
1
>>>a[2]
3
```

So this maximum index of python `list` is `len(list) - 1` otherwise error is raised.